# function to count query results in zend

Tags: zend-framework

Is there another way to count no of rows returned by a query.The following code returns 1 even though there is no result returned.(i am working on ZEND).

```
$this->view->overdue_query = $overdue_query->fetchAll();
/*Get overdue count */
$this->view->overdue_count = count($overdue_query);
```

Comment: is there a function like mysql_num_rows?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the output of a `var_dump($overdue_query)` returns.  I think you should be getting a plain array from fetchAll().  Could you please post that?

Comment: @drew010 fetchAll() returns a Zend_Db_Table_Rows object. You can cast/convert it to an array with ->toArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->view->overdue_query = $overdue_query->fetchAll();
/*Get overdue count */
$this->view->overdue_count = count($overdue_query);//you are doing count on 
//your query and not the result of fetchAll
```

it should be instead

```
$this->view->overdue_query = $overdue_query->fetchAll();
 /*Get overdue count */
$this->view->overdue_count = count($this->view->overdue_query); 

//unless you're getting overdue_count in your view then you would do :
$count = count($this->overdue_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this should work I do it all the time.

```
$results = $overdue_query->fetchAll();
echo count($results);
```

If it does'nt maybe something else in your code is wrong its hard to tell. 
Also try toArray() to see if it changes anything.

```
$results = $overdue_query->fetchAll()->toArray();
echo count($results);
```

[Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html#zend.db.table.rowset.rows)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MMC that you are trying to count wrong thing. 
count($this->view->overdue_query); should do the trick.